# Getting the amount of memory a process is using

Tags: windows, memory, process

I'm trying to retrieve just the amount of memory a process is using. The closest thing I can get is

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq process.exe"
```

But this returns a bunch of stuff:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
process.exe                        3384 Console                    1     81,384 K
process.exe                        6156 Console                    1     30,204 K
process.exe                        1436 Console                    1     84,696 K
process.exe                         216 Console                    1    195,100 K
```

Is there any way (without downloading/installing any programs) that I can just get a numerical value of the amount of memory something is using?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx , right click on the columns and add additional columns

Comment: What are you trying todo? why not downloading something better from MS itself than clumsy task explorer that one gets by default?

Comment: Do you want to only strip everything except last column (and - as per your example - show 4 values) or additionally sum them all (and show only 1 value)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
1. Do a txt file paste this code:

```
get-process | Group-Object -Property ProcessName | 
Format-Table Name, @{n='Mem (KB)';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1KB)};a='right'} -AutoSize
```

Save as, something.ps1 then go to run (win+r) type: powershell 
enter. search the file you've created and run it. For example if you have this file on your desktop then go to your desktop in powershell (with cd command) then press tab key as much as it needed to find your file with it then enter. I hope you can understand it. It gives you the memory usage in KB. If you want in MB then change the "/1KB to /1MB"

If you dont want the name you can delete "Name" after the format table.
Also, if you want a specified process after get-process write:

```
-ProcessName exampleprocess
```

Note: If it don't want to run because scripts are disabled or something like this: open a powershell window and type:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```